::before Pseudo-element Not Displaying Below Form Despite z-index -1 Setting
I have a problem where an element created with ::before is not appearing below a form. Even after setting z-index to -1, it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?


.form::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <h1 class="form-title">Login Here</h1>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>




Yeah, CSS stacking context.

Does this answer your question? Can someone explain stacking contexts?

You need to remove the z-index from the element that needs to have a pseudo element underneath it, then it works.


.form::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

.form {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <h1 class="form-title">Login Here</h1>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>




z-index on wrapper will do nothing

Indeed, simply removing the z-index from the form does the trick. Updated.
